# the scanf for the function to my switch is adversely affecting the functions in it

Tags: c

When the function recordWeight() is executed and i enter the weight via scanf it works but then at the end it says "invalid input" which is a printf from the function getChoice used in the switch Choice, this "invalid input" message is ment to only appear when you choose the wrong option for the switch.
it isnt supposed to affect the functions in the switch.
 and i think it may be preventing values from appearing in the displayHistory() function... 
I would really appreciate any help!

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <ctype.h>
#define pause system("pause")
#define cls system("cls")
#define SIZE 50
#define flush fflush(stdin)


char getChoice();
void displayMenu();
void recordWeight(float a[], int *c);
void displayAverage(float a[], int c);
void highLow(float a[], int c);
void displayHistory(float a[], int c);


main(){
    int counter = 0;
    float weight[SIZE]={0.0};
    char choice;

    do {
        choice = getChoice();
        switch(choice){

        case 'A':
            recordWeight(weight,&counter);
            break; 
        case 'B':
            displayAverage(weight,counter);
            break;
        case 'C':
            highLow(weight, counter);
            break;
        case 'D':
            displayHistory(weight, counter);
            break;
        }//end switch

    }while (choice != 'E' );
}//end main

char getChoice(){
    char result = 0;
    do{
        displayMenu();
        scanf_s("%c", &result);
        flush;
        if(result != 'A' && result != 'B' && result != 'C' && result != 'D' && result != 'E'){
            printf("Invalid Selection\n");
        pause;}
    } while(result != 'A' && result != 'B' && result != 'C' && result != 'D' && result != 'E');
    return result;
}//end getChoice

void displayMenu(){
    cls;
    printf("Main Menu\n");
    printf("A) Record Weight\n");
    printf("B)Display Average Weight\n");
    printf("C)Display Highest and Lowest Weight\n");
    printf("D)History of recorded Weight\n");
    printf("E)QUIT!!!!\n\n");

    printf("Please Enter your selection: \n");
    return;
}//end displayMenu

void recordWeight(float *a,int *c){
    printf("please enter a your weight..\n");
    scanf("%f", &a[*c]);
    *c = *c + 1;
    if(c > 0){
    if(a[*c]>a[*c-1])
        printf("Good, You gained weight!\n");
    else if(a[*c] < a[*c-1])
        printf("Ew You lost weight!\n");
    else 
        printf("Your still the same weight as before...gain some weight!\n");
        pause;
    }
}//end recordWeight

void displayAverage(float a[], int c){
    float average, total = 0.0;
    int i;
    if(c> 0){
    for(i=0; i < c; i++)
        total = total + a[i];
     average = total/ c;
     printf("\nYour Average weight is %.2f\n",average);
     pause;}
    else
        printf("You must enter atleast one weight in order to use this function.");
    pause;
}

void highLow(float a[],int c){
    if(c > 0){
    float high= a[0], low= a[0];
    int i;
    for(i=0; i < c; i++){
        if(a[i]> high)
            high= a[i];
        if(a[i]<low)
            low = a[i];
    }
    printf("The thinest you have been is %i pounds\n", low);
    printf("The Fattest you have been is %i pounds\n", high);
    pause;}
    else 
        printf("You must enter atleast one weight in order to use this function.\n");
    pause;
}//end highLow

void displayHistory(float a[],int c){
    int i;
    if(c > 0){
    for(i=0;i < SIZE; i++)
        printf(" %i. You were %i pounds\n",i+1,a[i]);
    }
    else
        printf("You must enter atleast one weight in order to use this function.\n");
    pause;
}//end displayHistory
```

Comment: The trick is, you don't use `scanf()` for getting user input, because it's evil. You use `fgets()` instead.

Comment: The only dangerous use of `scanf()` is with `%s` that has no character limit as in `%20s`, and this evil use has not been used in the question code.

Comment: @DelanAzabani And how about `scanf_s("%c", &result);`, which does not work as one might think?

Comment: Okay i'll search up how to do fgets() and see if it works!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your problem is that the input for the weight leaves the newline in the input buffer.  Your `"%c"` format therefore gets the newline, which is not A or B or C or D or E and triggers the warning.

Your simplest fix is to use the format `" %c"` with a blank before the `%c`; this will skip whitespace, including newlines, before reading a non-blank character.

Comment: yes that fixed that! Thank you!! I realized it isnt what is preventing the new values of the array from displaying